# PHP MVC - Open a specific Tab using URL Format

Tags: php, jquery, model-view-controller

I'm using PHP MVC and I've written below code to Create URL & load core controller. My URL Format is like this - "/controller/method/params". Now I'm facing some issue with it if I try opening a specific Nav Tab by passing #id of the tab in the URL, It is ignoring that part. I want if I pass the Id of a tab then it should open that active tab. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
 <?php
  /*
   * App Core Class
   * Creates URL & loads core controller
   * URL FORMAT - /controller/method/params
   */

 class Core
 {  
    protected $currentController = 'Pages';
    protected $currentMethod= 'index';
    protected $params = [];

    public function __construct()
     {
       //print_r($this->getUrl());
       $url = $this->getUrl();

       if (empty($url) || !in_array("user_images", $url)){


       //Look in controller for first value
       if (file_exists('../app/controllers/'. ucwords($url[0]) . '.php' )) {
            //if exists, set as controller
            $this->currentController = ucwords($url[0]);
            //Unset 0 Index
            unset($url[0]);

          }



          require_once '../app/controllers/' . $this->currentController . '.php';
         
          //instantiate controller class
          $this->currentController = new $this->currentController;

          //check for second part of the url

          if (isset($url[1])) {
            if (method_exists($this->currentController, $url[1])) {
                $this->currentMethod = $url[1];
                unset($url[1]);
            }
          }

          //echo $this->currentMethod;
          // Get Params
          $this->params = $url ? array_values($url) : [];

          //call a callback with array of params

          call_user_func_array([$this->currentController, $this->currentMethod],
            $this->params);

       }
       



     }

    public function getUrl(){
        if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
            $url = rtrim($_GET['url'],'/');
            $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
            $url = explode('/',$url);
            return $url;
        }
    }
     
     
 }
```

What changes I can do in the getUrl method?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `#` is only used on the client side, the browser, as an anchor point to an element in the page. Also, it can be used on a JavaScript context to work with tabs etc.

It is not handled on server side, you should just sent parameters: `?tab=id`

You can than access the `tab` parameter in your server side script.

Comment: Hi Maarten, How Can I change my getURL method to accept "?" also?

Comment: The `tab` parameter comes in inside the `$_GET` automatically. So read it from there.

Comment: @Marteen The id is basically my bootstrap nav tab id for a specific tab. I want to load it by passing the id in the URL. Now could you please take a look at my code and let me know where should make this change?